# Remaining time with joda time

Tags: android, time, jodatime

i want learn remaining time to 18.30 in my Android application. But,in joda time code there are year, month and day. i want use joda time for remaining time without date.

My code is not refresing remaining time for another days and remaning time is negative value when date and time passed. So, i want remove date values.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now(); // now() : since Joda Time 2.0
                DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2014, 10, 30, 18, 30);

                Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.dayTime());

                PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                        .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day ", " days ")
                        .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour ", " hours ")
                        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minute ", " minutes ")
                        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" second ", " seconds ")
                        .toFormatter();
                 tw.setText(formatter.print(period));
```

i explained at https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMjX4.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text was not quite understandable due to some English mistakes. So this is probably the main reason why there is no answer yet. But your diagram is pretty clear and has shown your efforts (so I am wondering why there was no answer until now). Indeed you are searching for the **remaining time until next local time of 18:30**.

Here a Joda-solution:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime endDate = startDate.withTime(18, 30, 0, 0); // can move back in time!

if (startDate.toLocalTime().isAfter(new LocalTime(18, 30))) {
    endDate = endDate.plusDays(1); // compensation for having moved back
}

Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.dayTime());

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day ", " days ")
        .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour ", " hours ")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minute ", " minutes ")
        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" second ", " seconds ")
        .toFormatter();
System.out.println(formatter.print(period));

// output at now about 18:28 => 1 minute 48 seconds 
// output at now about 18:31 => 23 hours 59 minutes 1 second
```

As you can see the solution is somehow awkward. Such coding has been one of many reasons to develop my own library Time4J. It offers the following shorter solution without any if-conditions:

```
  PlainTimestamp start = SystemClock.inLocalView().now();
  PlainTimestamp end = 
    start.with(PlainTime.COMPONENT.setToNext(PlainTime.of(18, 30)));
  Duration<ClockUnit> duration = Duration.inClockUnits().between(start, end);

  String p = PrettyTime.of(Locale.UK).print(duration, TextWidth.WIDE, true, 3);
  System.out.println(p); // 23 hours, 40 minutes and 1 second
```

Personally I consider Joda-Time as outdated because most people instead want to use the new library built in Java-8 residing in the package java.time (which is not capable of duration formatting however). And there is also no real future development of Joda-Time (if we are honest since years). The project leader of Joda-Time seems to wish any further development in his new Threeten-Extra-library according to his blog posts.

Comment: Nice, can you give an example with Date please ? yy/mm/dd/hh/m/s

Comment: @David.C The type `java.util.Date` has no concept of a duration other than just computing the count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00Z. So it is practically impossible to realize a solution with that type. As best effort, we could convert the milliseconds to minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, years on base of approximations.